# Category Page Product Filter

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am new to prestashop and I am trying to create a simple product filter to be displayed on the category page.
I managed to output my filter on the page using the hook for the hookDisplayLeftColumn method, however I have a few questions.
Right now I am hooking to the leftColumn but the filter will show on any page that has it.I want to show it only on the category page.

```
public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params)
    {

        $data = array(
            'bar' => 'foo'
        );

        $this->context->smarty->assign($data);
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'categoryfilter.tpl');
    }
```

And this is the tricky part.How do I filter the products.
Is there any method I can hook to and filter the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only include your code in category pages use something like:

```
public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params)
{
    if (!isset($this->context->controller->php_self) or $this->context->controller->php_self != 'category')
         return false;

     $data = array(
         'bar' => 'foo'
     );

     $this->context->smarty->assign($data);
     return $this->display(__FILE__, 'categoryfilter.tpl');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hook to `actionProductListOverride`.

Hook is executed in [CategoryController](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/controllers/front/CategoryController.php#L212)

As you can see you get three properties in params array. Because they are passed by reference you can assign them your own filtered product list and `CategoryController` will have your filtered data.

Make sure you set `hookExecuted` to `true`, also the data structure of `catProducts` should match with the one that `CategoryController` normally generates and `nbProducts` should have the **total** count of your filtered products.

For the first part of your question, sadlyblue gave you the answer.

Comment: Great explanation! Unfortunately I cant mark both answers as solved.