# Prestashop total products in category

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I've changed mysql query so It's not getting products that has quantity = 0 by adding:

```
and p.quantity > 0
```

to:

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(p.quantity, 0) as quantity, MAX(product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute) id_product_attribute, product_attribute_shop.minimal_quantity AS product_attribute_minimal_quantity, pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`,
                    pl.`available_later`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`, pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, MAX(image_shop.`id_image`) id_image,
                    il.`legend`, m.`name` AS manufacturer_name, cl.`name` AS category_default,
                    DATEDIFF(product_shop.`date_add`, DATE_SUB(NOW(),
                    INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).'
                        DAY)) > 0 AS new, product_shop.price AS orderprice
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                    ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`

                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa
                ON (p.`id_product` = pa.`id_product`)
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product_attribute', 'pa', false, 'product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1').'
                '.Product::sqlStock('p', 'product_attribute_shop', false, $context->shop).'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang` cl
                    ON (product_shop.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category`
                    AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl').')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl
                    ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image` i
                    ON (i.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)'.
                Shop::addSqlAssociation('image', 'i', false, 'image_shop.cover=1').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_lang` il
                    ON (image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image`
                    AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer` m
                    ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`
                WHERE p.quantity > 0 AND product_shop.`id_shop` = '.(int)$context->shop->id.'
                    AND cp.`id_category` IN('.implode(',',$cats_array).')'
                    .($active ? ' AND product_shop.`active` = 1' : '')
                    .($front ? ' AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")' : '')
                    .($id_supplier ? ' AND p.id_supplier = '.(int)$id_supplier : '')
                    .' GROUP BY product_shop.id_product';
```

Everything is working but pagination shows total products wrong. It shows total count with products with quantity = 0 (before changes).

I found that the variable with total count is $nb_products and It's in pagination.tpl.

Where can I find code that sets this variable?

Answer (score 1):

You modified the main SQL but you didn't modify the SQL above it which is used for total count.

[/classes/Category.php Line 702](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Category.php#L702)

```
/** Return only the number of products */
if ($get_total) {
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(cp.`id_product`) AS total
            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
            '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`
            WHERE cp.`id_category` = '.(int)$this->id.
        ($front ? ' AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")' : '').
        ($active ? ' AND product_shop.`active` = 1' : '').
        ($id_supplier ? 'AND p.id_supplier = '.(int)$id_supplier : '');

    return (int)Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($sql);
}
```

Though I wouldn't be modifying core files but use a module with a hook to create a [custom category page filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032123/category-page-product-filter/#46041014).